# trying scrape this page with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape this page/iframe with selenium/python but I can't insert any text in this selected form.

[link](https://ibb.co/cF8ZRZP)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://web.transparencia.pe.gov.br/despesas/despesa-geral/'
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='html_selectug']")
el.click()
```

When I try to get the listbox:

```
el_cl = el.find_element_by_class_name('chzn-select')
el_cl.click()
```

An exception is raised

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select class="chzn-select"> could not be scrolled into view
```

any tips?

Comment: Can you tell me why so many people write "scrap" instead of "scrape"? Scrapping is throwing something out as garbage, scraping is extracting the data from a web page.

Comment: What error do you get? And I don't see any selected form.

Comment: When I try to get the listbox:

'el_cl = el.find_element_by_class_name('chzn-select')'
'el_cl.click()'

An exception is raised

'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <select class="chzn-select"> could not be scrolled into view'

Answer (score 0):

The class name 'chzn-select' is not the correct class for the list you are trying to click(the one specified in the screenshot).

You can try getting all the options and click particular option by the text like below

```
AllOptions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='html_selectug']/select/option")
for option in AllOptions:
             if(option.get_attribute("value")=="option text you want to click")
                option.click()
                break
```

Comment: thx, but I don't know if you did notice but `option.text` is always a empty string

Comment: Verified with get_attribute("value") it works. Let me know if you still face probem.

Comment: You gave me a great clue. These options are display inactive (you can see the grey color code if you want inspect the elements). I had to make them active with js code.

Answer (score 0):

[Amith YR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4300192/amith-yr) gave me a great clue. The options are display-inactive (you can see the grey color code if you want inspect the elements). I had to make them active with js code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://web.transparencia.pe.gov.br/despesas/despesa-geral/'
driver.get(url)
sleep(10)

# activate the options
js = "document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('chzn-select')" \
     "[1].style.display = 'inline';"
driver.execute_script(js)

# now, I'm able to grab the listbox options
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='html_selectug']/select/option")
options[4].click()
```